# Razor Html Partial model

Tags: razor

I have a razor view, where I want to use a razor subcomponent. My main razor file looks like this

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage<ContentModels.Contentpage>
@using ContentModels = Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels;

@{
    Layout = "master.cshtml";
    var components = new List<Bodytext>();
    if (Model.Content.Mixed != null && Model.Content.Mixed.Any()) {
        components = Model.Content.Mixed.Select(e => new Bodytext(e)).ToList();
    }
}

<div>contentpage</div>

<ul class="team__employee-list">
    @foreach (var component in components){
        if (component.IsDocumentType("Banner")) {
            <li>
                @component.Title 1
                @Html.Partial("Components/cmp-banner", component)
            </li>
        }
        if (component.IsDocumentType("BodyText")) {
            <li>
                @component.Title 2
            </li>
        }
    }
</ul>
```

and my sub component like this

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage

<div>@model.Title</div>
```

but I get this error

```
Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: The 'inherits' keyword is not allowed when a 'model' keyword is used.


Source Error: 


Line 1:  @inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
Line 2:  
Line 3:  <div>banner</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It had to be

```
@Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("Title")
```